# A simple Python HTTP proxy

Tags: python, proxy

What is the simplest way to create a HTTP proxy with Python? As far as I can understand, it should be possible to create the proxy relatively easily with a couple lines of code using the standard library HTTP server features and `urlopen` or Requests.

Comment: What kind of proxy - HTTP? SOCKS? And what's the use case?

Comment: Sorry for not being more precise. I would like it to be an HTTP proxy server. The use case is just to use as one would a normal proxy server. As simple as possible.

Comment: Well in this case you might rather want to use a normal proxy server (Squid, Privoxy, Polipo). If you want a custom proxy, use Apache/mod_proxy ;)

Comment: Thing is.. I want to write my own. Hmm and to me, even the simple ones like the one Brian linked looks a bit difficult to me.

Comment: @Jake: It's not clear to me how you could expect anything much simpler than the one I linked.  It barely does anything.

Comment: I am probably not sufficient enough in python yet. I see your point in the code being relatively short, but it seems a bit complicated. I guess i will have to study a bit more hehehe.

Comment: Today I tried going through the proxy I linked to to look for chunks of it that were unnecessary, but didn't find much in it that could be eliminated excepting the `method_CONNECT` stuff, which relates to stuff you can probably ignore for the sake of simplifying your proxy.

Comment: See https://gist.github.com/mrts/2eefdf0f992f0f0e2269308fc6486011 for a simple Python 3 HTTP proxy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One incredibly simple one is [python-proxy](http://code.google.com/p/python-proxy/).  I found it on the list of python proxies at [xhaus](http://proxies.xhaus.com/python/), which was the top result when I googled "python proxy server" (sans quotes).

Comment: This answer is now out of date. The link to python-proxy goes to Google Code, which closed years ago. You may be able to get it if you have an old Google Code account.

Comment: @BoarGules: The link still lets me download the source, even if I open it in an incognito window.

Comment: But not me. Anonymous users not allowed. I think your incognito window isn't as incognito as you think.

Comment: The python-proxy code was exported to Github more than once, e.g. https://github.com/inject2006/python-proxy

Comment: I am author of proxy.py, lightweight http, https and websockets proxy server distributed as a single Python file with no external dependency. https://github.com/abhinavsingh/proxy.py

Answer (score 4):

[Twisted](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Twisted-Examples) lets you build simple ones, if you don't mind the complexity that is twisted.

Comment: Yeah.. I was kinda trying to avoid twisted... I think it is a bit hard :(