# Android: How to view the entire content of httprequest and httpresponse

Tags: android, proxy, httprequest, httpresponse, webproxy

Are there any tools on mac (other than charlesproxy) or programming techniques to view the entire content of each httprequest and response originating from an android application.

I tried printing them but then the httpresponse gets consumed if I do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not wish to use Charles Proxy consider some Java or Python based logging proxies. One that I had seen a few years ago was Grinder (Java based). Here is the page that shows how to [start it](https://theholyjava.wordpress.com/2011/07/28/simple-logging-http-proxy-with-grinder/). And here is the [home page](http://grinder.sourceforge.net/).

For a Python based proxy check this discussion [seriously simple python HTTP proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412581/seriously-simple-python-http-proxy) and this one [Python proxy.. A simple one!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480147/python-proxy-a-simple-one).