# how to embed a web browser on a webpage

Tags: python, browser, streaming

I am looking to embed(stream) a web browser running from my vps on a webpage. I'm just wondering what the best way to do that would be. preferably using a python framework, But I'm just not sure where to start. I'm open to any suggestions, thanks!

Comment: How about a text box where you enter a URL. Use the 'requests' module to fetch the html from your vps and then return the html to the page in a different frame. It's just really basic proxy. This method will likely not work if the page you're loading makes asynchronous calls back to the server.

Comment: Yea thanks, that is a really good idea, but what would happen if the person wanted to click on a link or tab on the webpage, Do you think there  would be someway to fetch the html everytime somebody were to click on a link that would take them to another URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is likely a python proxy server. Fortunately other people have also been interested in such a thing. Take a look at [this stack overflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480147/python-proxy-a-simple-one), as it has a number of suggestions on simple python based proxies you may want to try.

Comment: Thanks, this helps a ton!! Just out of curiosity, do you think python would be the best language for this?

Comment: Python will certainly work. But in all honesty, there are tools that are more purpose built for this task. Your best bet is probably just to use NGINX configured as a reverse proxy. [Here is an article describing the basic configuration of an NGINX reverse proxy](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/).